# Count a simple A-B testing ID with Module from any string

Tags: php, algorithm, hash

I have a quite few unique strings that I need to map to numbers 1,2,3.

How to count a simple number 1,2,3 from a random ascii string, so that approx 33.3% of strings will return 1, 33.3% of strings will return 2, and 33.3% of strings will return 3?

The string can be anything like XYZDA, JKLLK, DSAJKL, DASDSA
For example:

DASDSA could always return 1.

JKLLK could always return 2.

etc.

Could the alphabet ASCII values be somehow counted together with a for loop and then the total amount to be MOD 3, or is there a faster hash algorithm available? How is this done in PHP most efficiently?

Each unique string must always return the same number 1,2,3 when the function is called again.

Comment: _"Could the alphabet ASCII values be somehow counted together with a for loop and MOD 3"_ - you could do that, but I am not sure how close to your desired 33% distribution that would get you, it will probably depend on your actual input data.

Comment: thanks, its enough to get approximately 33%. When there is a high amount of samples its going to be ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to compute the MD5, take the first byte and apply a modulo:

```php
function hash3($str)
{
    $md5 = md5($str, true);
    return ord($md5[0]) % 3 + 1;
}

echo hash3('XYZDA');
echo hash3('JKLLK');
echo hash3('DSAJKL');
echo hash3('DASDSA');
```

Output:

```
3312
```

Comment: To make this a little more evenly spread (as 16/3 is not perfect), you could hexdec(substr(md5($srt),0,8)) and mod that?

Comment: Good point, I will accept the answer with this fix

Comment: @Tom @Robbie It spreads correctly because I used the binary version of MD5 (by passing `true` as second parameter).

Answer (score 1):

So the ASCII alphabet has 52 characters (A-Z and a-z). If we make 3 sections of these 52 characters, we will divide the ASCII alphabet in 3 parts (33.33% each part).

Lets call A,B,C the 3 parts.

Given a random letter, it could be 33.33% in A section, 33.33% in B section and 33.33% in C section.

So given a random String, if we count the number of characters belonging to section A,B, and C (lets say that in the random string the section A has 2 characters, the section B has 1 and the section C has 4) and takes the max (4 , section C) the probability of this is near to 33,33%

So, now we map A -> number 1 , B -> number 2 , C-> number 3.

And this random String (as it had 4 characters of section C) would be mapped to a 3

Obviously, this depends of the dataset, but I think it's a good aproach.

Let me know if I'm wrong at some point or if I didn't explain it as good as needed

Comment: thanks, I am looking for PHP code to do that ! :)